# Delete all message from a specific user in a channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

this is a line of code to delete an amount of message in a text channel in discord

```py
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

If i use `purge` function it will delete all message **everyone** sent. But I only want to delete message **from a specific user** like mee6, not all the message from everyone in the channel.

May I know how? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `check` argument of [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge):

```
user = user_to_delete
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount, check=lambda m: m.author == user)
```

Comment: Ya it is works for me. Thank you very much!